# I need to count number of visible images in screen using selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to count number of visible images in screen using selenium

I'm slippting `xpath` in to two:

```
Actual_xpath=//div[@id='ShowBox']/descendant::div[contains(@class, 'ShowColumn ')]/descendant::a[@class='logo']
```

slippted in two:

```
homePageShowLogoPartOne_XPATH=//div[@id='ShowBox']/descendant::div[
homePageShowLogoPartTwo_XPATH=]/descendant::div[contains(@class,'ShowColumn ')]/descendant::a[@class='logo']
```

While running the script:-

```
int showCount = driver.findElements(
                        By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoImage_XPATH"))).size();


//System.out.println("hai");

System.out.println("hai123");
int j = 0;
System.out.println("hai456");


for (int i = 1; i <= showCount; i++) {
    // Getting Shows title from My Shows page
    System.out.println("hai789");
    log.info(driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoPartOne_XPATH"+ i + driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoPartTwo_XPATH")))))).isDisplayed());

    System.out.println("hai1011");  

    j = j + 1;
}
log.info(j + "  shows are present in GET TO KNOW THE SHOW section (Count of only shows which are displaying on screen).\n");
```

While running script getting for 'homePageShowLogoPartTwo_XPATH' as

> invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath
>   expression ]/descendant::div[contains(@class,'ShowColumn
>   ')]/descendant::a[@class='logo']

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide us the html portion please?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by an error in this section of code:

```
log.info(driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoPartOne_XPATH"+ i + driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoPartTwo_XPATH")))))).isDisplayed());
```

Within the By.xpath section Instead of using

```
ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoPartTwo_XPATH")
```

You've used

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoPartTwo_XPATH"))
```

Which is why you're getting the exception.
Change it to fetch the property instead and it will work as expected.

```
log.info(driver.findElement(By.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoPartOne_XPATH") + i + ObjRepoProp.getProperty("homePageShowLogoPartTwo_XPATH"))).isDisplayed());
```